# How to render pdf into web browser in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, httpresponse

I have files in server for whom i want to keep the url confidential. For this, i created a controller that fetch the data and ultimately render it to the web broswer.

In the view

```
<%= link_to "Click to view the file", file_proxy( user.pdf_file_url ) %>
```

In users_heper.rb

```
def file_proxy(url)
  file_proxy_path(url: url)
end
```

In the routes.rb

```
get "file_proxy" => "file_proxy#fetch"
```

In the controller

```
def FileProxy < ApplicationController
  def fetch
    response = HTTParty.get params[:url]
    render response
  end
end
```

I'm getting an `<HTTParty::Response:0x10cd6e6a8 parsed_response="%PDF-1.3......" is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Do you know how to tweak this code so that it can display the PDF file correctly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `render` that way. It's expecting very specific options. In this case it probably looks like:

```
pdf_content = HTTParty.get(params[:url])
send_data(pdf_content, disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/pdf')
```

As a note, you probably want to limit what sorts of things that tool fetches or someone will eventually abuse it.